# android: On orientation change custom view,view not changing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a custom view element inside my activity and 2 xml designs. 1 for landscape and 1 for horizontal mode but when the orientation of the app changes the activity changes to the landscape xml but the custom view keeps its horizontal design.
can someone help me?. must i implement my own way of changing the layouts on the configuration change or something else?.

```
public class NavigationDashBoard extends LinearLayout implements
        ITurnByTurnContract.DashboardView,
        TextToSpeechUtils.ITextToSpeechDelegate,
        IRouteContract.ViewNavigationPresenter,
        SVGPresenter.svgLoadDelegate{


    public NavigationDashBoard(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context,null);
    }

    public NavigationDashBoard(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        init(context, attributeSet);
    }


    public NavigationDashBoard(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, @AttrRes int defStyleAttr){
        super(context,attributeSet,defStyleAttr);
        init(context,attributeSet);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.NavigationDashboardStyle);

        mVoiceEnabled = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.NavigationDashboardStyle_navigation_voice,DEFAULT_VOICE);
        mSpeedEnabled = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.NavigationDashboardStyle_navigation_show_speed, DEFAULT_SPEED);
        a.recycle();
        onCreate();
    }

    private void onCreate(){
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.route_navigation_dashboard_tool, this, true);

        mSmallFrame = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.small_route_icon_frame);
        mSmallPoiIcon = (AppCompatImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.route_navigation_dashboard_route_poi_small);
        mSmallDirectionJunction = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.route_navigation_dashboard_route_junction_small);
        mSmallDirectionsIcon = (AppCompatImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.route_navigation_dashboard_route_direction_small);

        mdirections = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.route_navigation_dashboard_route_message);
        mdirections.setOnClickListener(new SpeakRepeatListener());
        mDirectionsIcon = (AppCompatImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.route_navigation_dashboard_route_direction);
        mDirectionJunction = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.route_navigation_dashboard_route_junction);
        mPoiIcon = (AppCompatImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.route_navigation_dashboard_route_poi);

        mAudio = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.route_navigation_dashboard_volume);
        mAudio.setOnClickListener(new OnMute());

        mSvg = new SVGPresenter();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found my problem, I had to override the onConfigurationChanged

```
@Override
    protected void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            removeAllViews();
            onCreate();
    }
```

Comment: Don't do it this way, the activity creates your views then removes them and then creates them again which is a waste, do it the right way and you app will work smoother and better, I responded with an answer for you :)

Comment: hi, normally you would be right about that the app build the view 2 times. but i've found the core problem. the orientation changes are blocked in the manifest file for this activity. so alle changes must be manual for this activity.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to help you, post your `route_navigation_dashboard_tool.xml`

but from what I'm seeing now your doing it all wrong, let me explain:

1. Create a `my_layout.xml` (call it what you wish), include your custom View inside with tags:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <com.example.yourpackage.NavigationDashBoard
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/my_nav_board"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"/>
   ```

   **Importent:** You don't need a layout for Portrait and another for Landscape, you create only one and Android will use it to display for both.

   **Note:** the only reason to create two layouts for each orientation is if your planning to display things totally different in the layout, like more data or another screen for tablets.
2. Load this Layout from your Activity `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);`
3. Find your custom view in your Activity's **onCreate()** after **setContentView()**:

   ```
   NavigationDashBoard navBoard = (NavigationDashBoard) findViewById(R.id.my_nav_board);
   ```
4. Modify your method in the **NavigationDashBoard.class**, there is no need to inflate your layout inside it self.

   ```
   private void onCreate(){

       mSmallFrame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.small_route_icon_frame);
       mSmallPoiIcon = (AppCompatImageView) findViewById(R.id.route_navigation_dashboard_route_poi_small);
       mSmallDirectionJunction = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.route_navigation_dashboard_route_junction_small);
       mSmallDirectionsIcon = (AppCompatImageView) findViewById(R.id.route_navigation_dashboard_route_direction_small);

       mdirections = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.route_navigation_dashboard_route_message);
       mdirections.setOnClickListener(new SpeakRepeatListener());
       mDirectionsIcon = (AppCompatImageView) findViewById(R.id.route_navigation_dashboard_route_direction);
       mDirectionJunction = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.route_navigation_dashboard_route_junction);
       mPoiIcon = (AppCompatImageView)     findViewById(R.id.route_navigation_dashboard_route_poi);

       mAudio = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.route_navigation_dashboard_volume);
       mAudio.setOnClickListener(new OnMute());

       mSvg = new SVGPresenter();

   }
   ```
5. In your Activity after you found navBoard, you need to find your custom View's children so you call the method that you designed to do that:

   ```
   navBoard.onCreate()
   ```
6. Your app should be ready, the view will be recreated (it will get destroyed and then created again) by the Activity every screen orientation change, also you can now control the custom view from the activity so you can set data to it after it get recreated.

**Advice:** learn to use Fragments (from support libraries), the steps I written will work the same, the only change is you don't have setContentView() and instead you inflate a view :)

**Hope this helps, Good Luck!**